# Removing multiple views after a model has been deleted

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

My application is structured like this: There is a Sidebar which contains many items and is generated by a `SidebarView`. The `SidebarView` invokes an `ItemView` for every item in the sidebar:

```
render: ->
  view = new ItemView({model: the_item})
  $(@el).append(view.render().el)
```

Then there is a `ShowView` which displays the item in the main div. There is also a button, which is used to delete the item.

```
events:
  "click #destroy-button" : "destroy"

destroy: () ->
  @model.destroy()
  this.remove()

  return false
```

It removes the `ShowView` from the DOM tree and sends a DELETE request to the server. But what is the best way to remove the `ItemView` from the sidebar? Adding IDs like `<div class="item" data-index="123"></div>` and then remove the items via the data-index? I have seen somebody using `jQuery.data` to bind data to the DOM tree. But both solutions look a bit smelly. Is there an elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: why not just bind your view's render to the destroy event and only render anything in your view when there's data in your model? do you want to delete only to conserve memory or is it just that you want the visibility to go away?

Comment: I want the visibility to go away. How do I bind to a models destroy event, given I have a `destroy` method in the `ItemView` which removes the view? Should I place the binding in the `initialize` or in the `render` function?

Comment: in your view's initialize method: this.model.bind('destroy', this.render) - no need to have a destroy method on your view if you just bind the model's destroy event to the view's render method

Comment: I have extended your demo. The code does not work (and I can't figure out, why), but you get the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/KMT74/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ItemView should handle the "remove" button. The sequence goes like this:

1. You hit the *remove* button.
2. That triggers an event on the appropriate ItemView.
3. The ItemView destroys the model.
4. Destroying the model triggers a `'destroy'` event from the model.
5. The ItemView listens for the `'destroy'` event and removes itself when it happens.

So, your ItemView would look something like this:

```
class ItemView extends Backbone.View
    events:
        'click .del': -> @model.destroy()
    initialize: ->
        @model.on('destroy', @remove)
    render: ->
        # ...
        @
    remove: =>
        $(@el).remove()
        # And whatever other cleanup tasks you have...
```

That way your views will respond appropriately if one of your Item models is destroyed by someone else.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/KMT74/1/

And if someone else renders the delete button then you'd just need to call `destroy` on the appropriate model instance and the ItemView would remove itself. See the *kill first* button in the demo for an example. You could use a `data-id` attribute on the ItemView's `el` to associate models with their views and then do something like:

```
your_destroy_button_handler: (ev) ->
    item = @collection.get($(ev.target).data('id'))
    item.destroy()
```

but it would be cleaner for the ItemView to render its own delete button.

Also, this:

```
events:
  "click #destroy-button" : "destroy"
```

is going to be a problem as you'll have duplicate `id` attributes, use a class for the button instead:

```
events:
  "click .destroy-button" : "destroy"
```

Comment: But the `ItemView` does not render the delete button. It is rendered by the `ShowView`. Can I somehow invoke the `ItemView`? Or can I delete the model from the collection and rerender the sidebar?

Comment: @iblue: Why doesn't the ItemView render its own delete button? I've added a bit more discussion on how you could handle things if you don't want the ItemView to handle its own delete button.

Comment: After upgrading to backbone 0.9.1, a destroyed model will automatically be removed from the containing collections. I now just `MyCollection.bind 'all',     @render` in the `SidebarView`.